# What is the variance for time series data? How can it be computed?

Tags: time-series, variance, autocorrelation, autoregressive

I have learnt time series courses but may have forgotten some important and basic pieces. For typical times series data say AR data, there is only one observation at a time. How do you define the variance and compute it? Please help! Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that you have one observation at each time, but this is the realization of the stochastic process $\{y_t: t \in 1,2,\dots\}$ behind the data you observe, where for stochastic process I mean a collection of univariate random variables defined on some probability space.

Typically, time series are defined by specifying a model for the individual components of the process, for example an AR(1): $y_t = \phi y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$, where $\epsilon_t \sim WN(\sigma^2)$, i.e. $\epsilon_t$ is a white noise with variance $\sigma^2$.

So, for a AR(1), assuming that the process is [weakly stationary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process), the variance of each random variable $y_t$ does not depend on time t, and you can compute it as

$Var(y_t) = \phi^2 Var(y_{t-1})+\sigma^2 \implies Var(y_t) = \frac{\sigma^2}{1-\phi^2}
$